# How can I fetch data from API using an ID passed to a function when clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have used hooks in index.js to fetch data from an API. The data is displayed in rows and every row has a button with `onClick={() => EditExercise(item.idexercise)}`. *EditExercise* is a function in a .jsx file that receives the id and fetches a single item from the same API.

```
function EditExercise(id){
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/Exercises/GetEditId?id=${id}")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setItem(result);
            },
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
        }
        )
    }, [])

    if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
        <input type="text" id="name">{item.exerciseName}</input>
        <input type="text" id="desc">{item.instructions}</input>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to return a couple of input texts to display data like "name" and "description" using that ID. The error is indicating that I'm using an invalid hook call.